# How to flat array but to take only first index ? Js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to flat arrays but i can't to use flat().

First check example of my arrays

```
let arr = [
 ['test1' , 'test1'],
 ['test2' , 'test2'],
 ['test3', true],
 ['test4' , false]
];
```

What is problem here?

I need to get only first item 'test1' , 'test2', 'test3', 'test4' and push to one array

After that I want to my array be;

['test1' , 'test2' , 'test3' , 'test4' ];

What I'm try:

```
let arr = [
 ['test1' , 'test1'],
 ['test2' , 'test2'],
 ['test3', true],
 ['test4' , false]
];
```

let newArr = arr.flat();

but I got all items not first index in each array

Comment: `flat` is used to turn a multidimensional array in to a 1d array. What you are looking for is `map`: `arr.map(item => item?.[0])`

Comment: Well `.flat()` does the thing that the word "flatten" means when you're talking about lists of values. What you want to do is something else, which is to `.map()` the array to an array of the first elements of the component arrays.

Comment: Please accept an answer as the solution if the problem is solved to close the question

Comment: @sisihop96 I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [ ['test1' , 'test1'], ['test2' , 'test2'], ['test3', true], ['test4' , false] ];

const res = arr.map(([ e ]) => e);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Array.map()` first,then invoke `Array.flat()`

```js
let arr = [
 ['test1' , 'test1'],
 ['test2' , 'test2'],
 ['test3', true],
 ['test4' , false]
];

let result = arr.map(i => i[0]).flat()
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
let arr = [
 ['test1' , 'test1'],
 ['test2' , 'test2'],
 ['test3', true],
 ['test4' , false]
];

console.log(arr.map(innerArr => innerArr[0]));
```